# Web site to dll

Tags: dll

I need to compile my web site, is it possible without converting to a web project first?

Comment: You mean an ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC site in Visual Studio?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll need to provide a lot more detail for your question to get answered in a reasonable way. In fact, the way it is now, your question may well get closed by the community as "not a real question". Don't let that bother you, just try again with a lot more detail. People **are** ready and willing to help. Probably worth reading [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [this page on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Best,

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to "protect" his code for any deployment.

If this is a .Net project you can try hide some code using codebehind components in ASP.NET.
Here is an small tutorial about it:
http://asp.net-tutorials.com/basics/code-behind/

For older projects you may have to build a cgi binary application, but as already mentioned here, add some more details to specify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a VS Web Deployment project. This exists as a separate project in your solution but can compile and copy the existing web project to a different directory.

There's a reasonable write-up of it [on this blog](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2010/01/07/deploy-aspnet-web-applications-with-web-deployment-projects/) with step-by-step instructions. You'll need to download and install the new project type separately though ([2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en), [2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=89f2c4f5-5d3a-49b6-bcad-f776c6edfa63&displaylang=en))

Comment: I have a already closed web site made in web developer 2008. That i like to compile to dll. But since it wasn´t made as a project i dont know if it´s possible.